# Making simple custom geom - variation of geom_rect() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to make a simple custom geom that will essentially place a 'frame' around  ggplot panels. I am aware this is also possible to do within the theme, but I might like to map other aesthetics to it like color and so on. What I would like is to simply modify geom_rect so that by default it just has xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax values of Inf and -Inf, a fill of NA, and a color like black or grey20.

However, I've tried to follow some of the code examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) to just update an existing geom, and this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw and error, but it simply doesn't plot anything.

```
library(tidyverse)

GeomFrame <- ggproto("GeomFrame",
                     GeomRect,
                     default_aes = aes(colour = "grey20",
                                       fill = NA,
                                       size = 1,
                                       linetype = 1,
                                       xmin = -Inf,
                                       xmax = Inf,
                                       ymin = -Inf,
                                       ymax = Inf)
)

geom_frame <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
                       ..., linejoin = "mitre", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomFrame, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
    params = list(linejoin = linejoin, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 10)) +
  geom_frame()
```

You should see that this just doesn't seem to do anything. What I would like it to look like is this:

```
ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 10)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = NA, color = "black", size = 1)
```

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ggproto object could look like this:

```r
GeomFrame <- ggproto("GeomFrame", GeomRect,
 default_aes = aes(colour = "grey20",
                   fill = NA,
                   size = 1,
                   linetype = 1,
                   alpha = 1,
                   xmin = -Inf, 
                   xmax = Inf, 
                   ymin = -Inf, 
                   ymax = Inf),
 
 required_aes = NULL
)
```

Your actual `geom_frame` function probably makes more sense as an annotation type geom, but as long as you give it some default data and an aesthetic mapping it should do what you need:

```r
geom_frame <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
                       position = "identity", 
                       ..., linejoin = "mitre", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = FALSE) {
  if(is.null(data)) {
    data <- data.frame(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)
    mapping <- structure(c(mapping, 
                 aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)),
                 class = "uneval")
  }
  
  layer(
    data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomFrame, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
    params = list(linejoin = linejoin, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

For example

```r
ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 10)) +
  geom_frame()
```

[image]

and

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_frame(size = 3, color = "red4")
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! A very small edit is that I think a comma is required after setting the default_aes()

Comment: Sorry Jamie - you're quite right. Fixed.

Comment: One small thing I've just realised, it actually doesn't recognise the overarching data specified at the top of the ggplot - is there a way to get around that? E.g., if I want to map color to a variable in the data, it now does not recognise the data. But I can specify the data again at the level of the geom and it works...

Comment: @Jamie this is because I switched the `inherit.aes = FALSE` and created a data object to allow the example without data to run. It seemed unlikely that you would need to inherit from the main plot data with an annotation such as this. If you want to, you can turn inherit.aes back to TRUE and remove the dummy data frame from the geom_frame function

Comment: Ah, you know what - it seems to be a very idiosyncratic mistake. In fact, I can call a color in the aes - it just didn't specifically work when the variable I was coloring by was called 'group'! I guess it is a specific term that the geom is looking for in terms of how the data is grouped or something. If I change the variable to the term 'which_group' or something else, it does work! And then additionally, changing inherit aes() to true just additionally allows color to be specific in the first call to ggplot and not just at the level of the geom itself. Thanks for your help Allan